# C# OleDbDataAdapter does not always return a value

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Im currently reading an excel file with the `OleDbDataAdapter`, everything worked fine. But now i wanted to read another file and now some fields are empty, but there is clearly a value in that specific field in excel.

I just need informations from the file, so i read the data into a two dimensional array, later on i use the data for further calculations.

The field im trying to read is a merged cell, but this worked fine in the last file...

There is also another strange behaviour, if the same excel is already opened, the `OleDbDataAdapter` returns another number of rows... (I fixed this with starting an excel process before.)

This is my code:

```
 // import the data from excel into a two dimensional list so it will be easy to navigate through
                var excelData = new List<List<string>>();
                var worksheetName = "theNameOfMyWorksheet";
                var connectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + pathToFile + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0'";
                OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                oledbConn.Open();
                var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName.Key + "$]", oledbConn);
                // Create new Database connection
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter
                {
                    SelectCommand = command
                };

                // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the excel worksheet.
                oleda.Fill(ds);
                foreach (var table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    var dataTable = (DataTable)table;

                    for (int e = 0; e < dataTable.Rows.Count; e++)
                    {
                        var rowItems = new List<string>();
                        var dataRow = (DataRow)(dataTable.Rows[e]);
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            var entry = dataRow.ItemArray[i];
                            rowItems.Add(entry.ToString());
                        }
                        excelData.Add(rowItems);
                    }
                }
                oledbConn.Close();
                return excelData;
```

Here you can see that there is no value after "Maschine"

[image: The Values are empty after "Maschine"]

And this is how my excel looks like:
[image]

Comment: Try using a library to read from the Excel file directly instead of using an OLEDB driver, eg [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). Excel isn't a database and trying to treat it like one causes .... issues. OLEDB has no concept of merged cells. Where would the value appear in? In field C, D, E...... or Y? ExcelDataReader on the other hand allows you to identify merged cells eg through the `MergeCells` property

Comment: Your screenshot shows merged rows too, not just merged cells. The data may simply not be where you think it is. Try using Visual Studio's [DataTable Visualizer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/datatable-visualizer-improvements/) to see the entire DataTable at once instead of individual rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos omg thanks, much better view!
But there is still no value visible....
The other excel-file (which works) does also contains merged cells, and the value appears on the first "merged cell".
Anyway, i will try the ExcelDataReader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PanagiotisKanavos recommended in the comments, i will now use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader).

Works perfectly for me, it is also way faster than doing it with OleDb.

Thanks!